# Swift 3: Defining var labels: [UILabel] fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, variable-declaration

I'm stuck at a variable declaration in Swift 3. My code looks like this:

*Beginning of code*

```
// Letter Buttons
@IBOutlet weak var LetterOneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LetterTwoButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LetterThreeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LetterFourButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LetterFiveButton: UIButton!

// Word Fields
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterOne: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterTwo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterThree: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterFour: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterFive: UILabel!

// Counter
@IBOutlet weak var CounterLabel: UILabel!

// Skip Button
@IBOutlet weak var SkipButtonLabel: UIButton!

// Define Variables
var index: Int = 0
```

The error appears in the following line:

```
var labels: [UILabel] = [WordLetterOne, WordLetterTwo, WordLetterThree, WordLetterFour, WordLetterFive]
```

Error message is "*Cannot use instance member 'WordLetterOne' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available*". Afterwards, another string is declared without any problems.

```
var letters: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

*End of code*

And help is highly appreciated!

*Edit:*

```
self.lazy var labels: [UILabel] = [WordLetterOne, WordLetterTwo, WordLetterThree, WordLetterFour, WordLetterFive]
```

is giving the errors "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'" and "Instance member 'WordLetterOne' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'"

Comment: The error message has already explained what is wrong. What is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to resolve the error, @CezaryWojcik

Comment: Don't use properties in a property initializer. The error message says "you can't do this", so the resolution is to not do this.

Comment: Make the property computed. Or make the *array* an `@IBOutlet` and remove the numbered variables.

Comment: define it as lazy: `lazy var labels: [UILabel] = [self.WordLetterOne, self.WordLetterTwo, self.WordLetterThree, self.WordLetterFour, self.WordLetterFive]`

Answer (score 0):

Like it says: when the runtime builds the array initalizer, the properties you're trying to put in the array are not defined yet (because `self` is not ready yet).

Try to make the properties static (depends on your actual situation).
Or -- initialize the `labels` array in the `init` method.

The definition of `letters` is ok because "A", "B", etc are constants.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me an example of how exactly that would look in the above mentioned case? Thanks in advance for your effort!

Comment: Try @vacawama's suggestion in the comment (lazy) -- sounds like a very clean solution (haven't tested it).